# Angular translate extend existing translations

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am trying to have external modules change my `$translateProvider.translation` on the main module. see this as a "tranlation plugin" for my app.

it seems like changing translations from the `$translate` service is not possible.

```
mymodule.service('MyService', function ($translateProvider) {
    var lib = function () {
    //EDITED FOR BREVITY
        this._registerTranslations = function (ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl.i18n) return;
            for (var name in ctrl.i18n) {
            /////////////////////////////
            // THIS IS THE PLACE, OBVIOUSLY PROVIDER IS NOT AVAILABLE!!!!
               $translateProvider.translations(name, ctrl.i18n[name]);
            //////////////////////////////
            }
        };
    //EDITED FOR BREVITY
    };
    return new lib();
});
```

anyone with a bright idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer your question: there's no way to extend existing translations during runtime with `$translate` service without using asynchronous loading. I wonder why you want to do that anyway, because adding translations in such a way means that they are already there (otherwise you would obviously use asynchronous loading).

Comment: Hi @Pascal, actually I have an UI designer where user can make his own controls and specify i18n for it. this control is then serialized to database. I only grab the control after the app has initialized and therefor have no access to `.config()`. Is this really wrong? Addding `$translate.translations = translations;` worked but you seem not to like it... Anyway I can implement this use case without changing code?

Comment: angular-translate is actually designed in a way that you have to tell angular-translate first, what translations you want to work with before it can use them (either by registering translations statically, or by using asynchronous loaders). I'm coming back to the issue on github and see what the team thinks about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Asynchronous loading](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading) page.  You can create a factory that will load a translation from wherever you want.

I created an Angular constant to hold new translations.  If I want to add a new translation, I add it to the constant.  Then in my custom loader, I first check the constant to see if the translation exists (either a new one, or an updated one).  If so, I load it from the constant.  If not, I load it from a .json file (or wherever you load your initial translations from).  Use `$translate.refresh()` to force translations to be reloaded and reevaluated.

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJh3Dz?p=preview)

The demo is pretty simple.  You would need to do a little more work if you wanted to just change a subset of the translations, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Thats nice! though I would have liked to have a more direct way to do it... I'll wait on @PascalPrecht input and see... thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer, this was usefull though I prefer to simplify things a bit. your way seems to be the only standard way of doing this. see https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/pull/612#issuecomment-46778725

Answer (score 0):

From the AngularJS docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

*You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API **for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts**. This is usually interesting only for reusable services whose behavior might need to vary slightly between applications.*

Providers are to be used with the application's `.config` function.  `$translateProvider` for configuration, `$translate` for other services and controllers.

Comment: thanks for your time! I know that though. my question is specifically oriented towards angular translate to find out a way, if there is one, to extend the translations data from a directive. I have started to have look at the source to find out but posted here in case someone else has done this.